# Running the same code at the beginning of many Express.js routes

Tags: node.js, express

Look at these routes:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var legacy = false;
    //LENGTHY CODE that sets legacy to true for old browsers

    if (legacy === false) {
        res.render('home');
    } else {
        res.render('legacy');
    }
});

app.get('/other', function (req, res) {
    var legacy = false;
    //LENGTHY CODE that sets legacy to true for old browsers

    if (legacy === false) {
        res.render('other');
    } else {
        res.render('legacy');
    }
});

//Many other routes like this with the legacy check.
```

Question is, how do I avoid repeating the **lengthy code** in each route? Putting it into a function is not really a solution because that begs the question, how do I avoid calling that function in each route?

Is there a good way out of this?

Is this what so-called middleware is for, maybe?

Ideas'd be appreciated.

Comment: Depends, for all routes you can use `app.all`, if it's only for some routes you can define a route that matches with a regex or a variable (`app.get('/:id')`) and validate the variable against a set of rules etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as you said this is exactly what middleware is for.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
   var legacy = false;
   if (legacy) {
       res.render('legacy');
   } else {
       next();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanx that is great to know. However, can you expand your answer to cover also the case if some routes don't want this legacy check? (Your answer covers the case where ALL routes need it)

Comment: @stackoverflowuser: you can pass patterns to use like `app.use(['/abcd', '/xyza', /\/lmn|\/pqr/], function(){})`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next()`.
Try this:

```
app.get(['/', '/other'], function(req, res, next){                                      
  //preprocessing here                     
  next();                                                                   
});
```

It accepts Path, Path Pattern, Regular Expression and Array.
If you do not want some paths to do this preprocessing then you use Regex to negate those paths.